# Android Grid View with Image and Text

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

I need to show text below every image in grid view. I have been able to put the images in grid view but how to put text below it? Below I'm posting the code snippets.

fragment_facility_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

</GridView>
```

FacilityAdapter.class

```
package com.androidbelieve.HIT_APP;

/**
 * Created by Akash on 2/13/2016.
 */
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FacilityAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;


    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.bank, R.drawable.bus,
            R.drawable.girlshostel , R.drawable.guesthouse,
            R.drawable.gym , R.drawable.library,R.drawable.sports

    };

    public String[] mThumbNames = {
            "Bank", "Bus Service","Guest House", "GYM","Fac1","Fac2"

    };

    // Constructor
    public FacilityAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View gridView;
        gridView = new View(mContext);



        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Thank You

Comment: http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/07/custom-grid-view-example-in-android.html

Answer (score 1):

I would rather suggest that instead of creating `ImageView` dynamically at run time and return that from your `getView()` method, you should create an `xml` for your each of the `list items`. Below is the sample `xml` with `ImageView` and `TextView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also you should follow `ViewHolder Pattern`to make your `GridView` memory efficient. Your `getView()` method will look alike this

```
@Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourxml,
                    null);
            holder.textview= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.imageview= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.imageView.getLayoutParams().width = yourImageWidth;
            holder.imageView.getLayoutParams().height = yourImageHeight;
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        holder.textview.setText(mThumbNames[position]);
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend this:

[SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html)

or use it by default like:

```
private Context mContext;
// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
     R.drawable.bank, R.drawable.bus,
     R.drawable.girlshostel , R.drawable.guesthouse,
     R.drawable.gym , R.drawable.library,R.drawable.sports
};
public String[] mThumbNames = {"Bank", "Bus Service","Guest House", "GYM","Fac1","Fac2"};
Simple adapter= new SimpleAdapter(mContext, List<?> your_list, R.layout.your_layout_file, from, to);
```

You also have to make a layout file and define how the image and text you would like to look for each gridview item like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/this_image_id_have_to_be_used_in_your_to_array"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/this_text_id_have_to_be_used_in_your_to_array"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: how can u just type and show the xml file so that i can get an idea